# generate datagrid row based on textbox input

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

how do you generate datagrid row based on user's input on the web, so if i input 5 on textbox then 5 rows will be generated vice versa.
i have tried this code of mine below but i keep on getting `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown` error everytime i try to run my program

my aspx.cs

```
private DataTable TempTable
{
    get { return (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"]; }
    set { ViewState["TempTable"] = value; }
}

public void dtTemp()
{
    TempTable = new DataTable();
    TempTable.Columns.Add("ID_", typeof(string));
    TempTable.Columns.Add("Name_", typeof(string));
    TempTable.Columns.Add("Phone_", typeof(string));
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int rowTotal = Int32.Parse(totalRow.Text);
    int i = 0;
    panelTest.Visible = true;

    dtTemp();
    DataRow dr = TempTable.NewRow();

    for (; ; )
    {
        if (i < rowTotal)
        {
            dr = TempTable.NewRow();
            dr["ID_"] = "";
            dr["Name_"] = "";
            dr["Phone_"] = "";
            TempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            grid1.DataSource = TempTable;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my previous code crashes my visual studio and it said i have no enough memory so i changed my code a little and it work.

```
public DataTable TempTable
{
    get; set;
}

public void dtTemp()
{
    TempTable = new DataTable();
    TempTable.Columns.Add("ID_", typeof(string));
    TempTable.Columns.Add("Name_", typeof(string));
    TempTable.Columns.Add("Phone_", typeof(string));
}

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    int rowTotal = Int32.Parse(txtRow.Text);

    dtTemp();
    DataRow dr = TempTable.NewRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowTotal; i++)
    {
        dr = TempTable.NewRow();
        dr["ID_"] = "";
        dr["Name_"] = "";
        dr["Phone_"] = "";
        TempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    grid1.DataSource = TempTable;
    grid1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try this below increase i++ in your forever loop for(;;)

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
 {
    int rowTotal = Int32.Parse(totalRow.Text);
    int i = 0;
    panelTest.Visible = true;

    dtTemp();
    DataRow dr = TempTable.NewRow();

    for (; ; )
    {
        if (i < rowTotal)
        {
            dr = TempTable.NewRow();
            dr["ID_"] = "";
            dr["Name_"] = "";
            dr["Phone_"] = "";
            TempTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            grid1.DataSource = TempTable;
            grid1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```